# "Hello from the pygame community"

Tags: python, pygame

When I executed the following code, instead of an error it said "Hello from the pygame community. [https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html"](https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html%22). It would be easier for me if it just included the error so I could fix it myself without posting the code in stackoverflow (for privacy reasons).

Here's the code:

```
# import the pygame module, so you can use it
import pygame

# define a main function
def main():
    # initialize the pygame module
    pygame.init()
    # load and set the logo
    logo = pygame.image.load("logo32x32.png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
    pygame.display.set_caption("minimal program")

    # create a surface on screen that has the size of 240 x 180
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((240, 180))

    # define a variable to control the main loop
    running = True

    # main loop
    while running:
        # event handling, gets all event from the eventqueue
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # only do something if the event is of type QUIT
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # change the value to False, to exit the main loop
                running = False

        # draw a green line from (0,0) to (100,100)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,255,0), (0,0), (100,100))

        # draw a green line from (0,100) to (100,0)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,255,0), (0,100), (100,0))

        # draw a rectangle outline
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (60,60,100,50), 1)

        # draw a filled in rectangle
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (60,120,100,50))

        # draw a circle
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (120,60), 20, 0)

        # draw a circle outline
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,255,0), (120,60), 20, 1)

        # draw a polygon
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0,255,0), ((140,60),(160,80),(160,100),(140,120),(120,100),(120,80)), 0)

        # draw a filled in poly
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0,255,0), ((140,60),(160,80),(160,100),(140,120),(120,100),(120,80)), 1)

        # draw a text
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render("Hello There", 1, (10, 10, 10))
        textpos = text.get_rect()
        textpos.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
        screen.blit(text, textpos)

        # update the screen
        pygame.display.flip()

    # quit pygame properly to clean up resources
    pygame.quit()

# end of the code
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Does this have an error? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want. I'm gonna guess, add at the very end: `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` and see if it was it.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't an error. That line is printed when you import pygame. None of your code is producing an error because none of it is being called. After you define the main function, make sure to call main().